# Properly filter streak data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have written a python script that calculates winning streaks of sports match outcomes.

For example, the dataframe for player *A* looks like this:

```
time  winner  loser  streak
1     A       B      1
2     A       C      2
3     A       D      3
4     B       A      0
5     A       F      1
6     A       G      2
7     H       A      0
8     A       X      1
9     A       Y      2
10    A       Z      3
```

The streak-column essentially contains a cumulative count of the wins, but it is reset to 0 when the respective player loses, because this ends the streak.

I now would like to output only streaks that are greater than 2, but obviously I want all matches that contributed to this streak.

In other words, the query would be like this: **Provide all matches that contributed to a streak greater than 2**

The result would look like this:

```
time  winner  loser  streak
1     A       B      1
2     A       C      2
3     A       D      3
8     A       X      1
9     A       Y      2
10    A       Z      3
```

How can this be achieved with Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to first detect the change points, the points where the streak goes to 0 *and* has been longer than $n$. You can do this with `pct_change` and a threshold on the `streak` column

```
streak_ends = np.where((df['streak'].pct_change() > 0) & (df['streak'] > 2))[0]
```

Then you just need to get the start point of the streak which is the end point minus the length of the streak

```
streaks = [slice(idx - df.loc[idx, 'streak'] + 1, idx + 1) for idx in streak_ends]
streaks
Out[86]: [slice(0, 3, None), slice(7, 10, None)]


df[streaks[0], ['winner', 'streak']]
Out[87]: 
  winner streak
7      A      1
8      A      2
9      A      3
```

---

UPDATE
**Turns out `itertools.grouper` does it this much better**

```
import itertools
df['A wins'] = df.winner == 'A'
# rolling groupby using itertools
groups = [list(s) for i, s in itertools.groupby(df['A wins'])]

# filter out streaks that are shorter than the desired period
# itertools.chain is needed to unpack the nested groups
streaks = list(itertools.chain(*[g if len(g) > 2 else [False] * len(g)
                                 for g in groups]))
df.loc[streaks, ['winner', 'streak']]
Out[83]: 
   winner streak
0       A      1
1       A      2
2       A      3
7       A      1
8       A      2
9       A      3
10      A      4
```

Comment: this works. however, for outputting as CSV I had to do this: `df[streak][['winner', 'streak']].to_csv(sys.stdout,index=False))`

Comment: one problem i see here is, that if I have a streak of 4, the `streak_ends` contain one streak twice, because the query matches for 3 and for 4. so I have duplicates then...

Comment: sorry, just saw your comment now. aren't you missing something in groups? I get this error: `KeyError: 'None of [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, .....]] are in the [index]'` when calling  `df.loc`